# Why does modal render below table?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, modal-dialog

Currently, my modal renders below my table after I press submit on the form. I thought it was a CSS issue earlier but now I'm fairly certain it's an issue with the javascript logic. I feel it may have something to do with the re-rendering of the table? Here are the relevant files and screenshots for context.

Table:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
import SampleQ from '../components/question.js';
import css from '../scss/style.scss';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import NavigationBar from "../components/Navbar/index";

export default class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showBackground: false
        };

        this.showBackground = () => {
            this.setState({ showBackground: true });
        };

        this.hideBackground = () => {
            this.setState({ showBackground: false });
        }
    }

    static getInitialProps({query: {categories, questions, answers}}) {
        return {postCs: categories, allQs: questions, allAs: answers}
    }

    createTable = () => {
        let table = [];

        let cats = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.postCs.length; i++){
            cats.push(<th key = {i}>{this.props.postCs[i].title}</th>);
        }

        table.push(<thead> <tr> {cats} </tr> </thead>);

        let index = 0;
        // Outer loop to create parent
        for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            let children = [];

            //Inner loop to create children
            for (let j = 1; j < 7; j++) {
                children.push(
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <SampleQ
                                amount={i}
                                question={this.props.allQs[(index)].title}
                                answer={this.props.allAs[(index)].title}
                                showBackdrop={this.showBackground}
                                hideBackdrop={this.hideBackground}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </td>);
                index++;
            }
            //Create the parent and add the children
            table.push(<tr>{children}</tr>)
        }

        return table
    };

    render() {
        let data = this.createTable();

        return (
            <div>
                <Layout showBackground={this.state.showBackground} title="lllll" />
                <Table striped bordered hover variant = "dark" className={css.table} hide={true}>
                    {data}
                </Table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Question:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import UserInput from './userInput.js';
import Feedback from "./feedback/feedback";
import Backdrop from "./backdrop";
import styles from '../scss/backdrop.scss';
import Layout from '../components/layout';

class SampleQ extends Component {
    static getInitialProps({query: {amount, question, answer}}) {
        return {specAmt: amount, specQ: question, specA: answer}
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showQuestion: false, // tracks visibility of first modal (the question modal)
            showFeedback: false, // tracks visibility of second modal (the feedback modal)
        };

        this.handleShow = () => {
            // show question and the backdrop when the user clicks a cell on the table
            this.setState({ showQuestion: true });
            this.props.showBackdrop();
        };

        this.handleHide = () => {
            this.setState({ showQuestion: false });
            this.props.hideBackdrop();
        };

        this.submitForm = event => {
            event.preventDefault();

            this.props.hideBackdrop(); // take down stars backdrop

            this.setState({
                showQuestion: false, // close question modal
                showFeedback: true, // should open Feedback modal
            });
        };

        this.closeFeedback = () => {
            // close Feedback modal and close backdrop so that it goes back to the table
            this.setState( { showFeedback: false });
            this.props.hideBackdrop();
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Button variant="outline-danger" size = "lg" onClick={this.handleShow}>
                    $ {this.props.amount}00
                </Button>

                <Modal
                    show={this.state.showQuestion}
                    onHide={this.handleHide}
                    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
                    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
                    backdrop={false}
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
                            Question
                        </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <p>
                            {this.props.question}
                        </p>
                        <div>
                            <UserInput
                                answer={this.props.specA}
                                handleClick={this.submitForm}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
                <Feedback
                    showModal={this.state.showFeedback}
                    handleHide={this.closeFeedback}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default SampleQ;
```

Feedback Modal (the one that renders below table)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { AiFillCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';
import styles from '../../scss/modalStyle.scss';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

class Feedback extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                show={this.props.showModal}
                onHide={this.props.handleHide}
                dialogClassName="modal-90w"
                aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
                className={styles.modal}
            >
                <IconContext.Provider
                    value={{
                        color: '#fff',
                        size: '70px',
                        className: styles.modalConfirmIconBox,
                    }}
                >
                    <AiFillCheckCircle />
                </IconContext.Provider>

                <Modal.Body className={styles.modalBody}>
                    <h4 className={styles.h4}>Congratulations!</h4>
                    <p className={styles.p}>That was the correct answer.</p>
                    <Button
                        className={styles.button}
                        variant="success"
                        block
                        size="lg"
                        onClick={this.props.handleHide}
                    >
                        OK
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}

export default Feedback;
```

[image: question]
[image: feedback]

Comment: Since you use modal in the outer component, simply write it outside `table` seems good.

Comment: that might actually help with my organization. thank you. the actual problem was for this seemed to actually be in the css though.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. The problem was setting "position: relative" in scss file and I'm guessing the other adjustments to the modal's position put it under the table.